# excel comparison in c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am comparing two excel files cell by cell in c#.
I want to color those cells which are not matching in the target file.
How can it be done without creating another file..

Comment: So you want to change the color of a cell?

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate file? If you have both open and are walking their cells, can't you can just update the target directly and save it when your done?

Comment: duplicate(assuming you have instances open). your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840251/is-there-a-way-to-color-selected-cells-of-an-excel-file-using-c/5840288#5840288)

Comment: I don't needd intermediate file..I want to color cells in the target file itself..

Answer (score 0):

You have to instances of excel open and look up cells? Then the way to changing a cell is not really far. Have you tried `Cell.Font.Color` on one of the active cells??